# How can I correct the lack of antialiasing for text with a gradient fill in SVG in Chrome?

Tags: svg

There is such an iridescent text based on linear-gradient made in svg, but also noticed errors ... visually:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 193 80">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient  id="linearGradient914">
      <stop id="stop910"
         offset="0"
         style="stop-color:yellow;" />
      <stop  id="stop912"
         offset="1"
         style="stop-color:red;" />
    </linearGradient>


    <linearGradient
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       y2="168.58255"
       x2="-127.96807"
       y1="168.58255"
       x1="-227.84294"
       id="linearGradient916"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient914" />
  </defs>
  <g  transform="translate(210.09778,-163.31157)"  id="layer1">
    <text  transform="scale(0.92185611,1.084768)" id="text817" y="178.24792" x="-228.11203"  style="font-size:41px;line-height:41px;">
  <tspan style="font-family:Gabriola;fill:url(#linearGradient916);" y="178.24792"  x="-228.11203"  id="tspan815">FREEDOM</tspan>
 </text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As seen in the text ragged edges as if this is a bitmap graphics in Google Chrome, but in Firefox and IE11 this is not ...

I changed the font size and the same font family and the situation does not change ... probably the only problem I have

What should I do that would not Google Chrome have a ragged edge in the text?

Comment: association : https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/850904/33274

Comment: On my system, I don't have the font "Gabriola" installed, and on both browsers I can see no problem. Therefore, I think this is related to the way the font is handled on your system. Is it installed locally, and what format does the font have?

Comment: @ccprog I have a Gabriola installed in my system ... also, the customer has installed/purchased webfonts and it is in all computers ..here is a screenshot of how the video I, https://cloud.mail.ru/public/GimD/PWsJT1BFd

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to convert the font to Bezier curves and everything was displayed perfectly

in solving the problem helped [moskus](https://toster.ru/q/544141?e=6660695#clarification_579193)